# How to get bold face text of Linux Libertine with LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, bold, libertine

I am trying to create a CV similar to the one created by [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21344/paul-gessler) ([GitHub](https://github.com/pdgessler/pdg-vita)). I am not using the Adobe Garamond fonts but instead Linux Libertine, everything works okay but the bold face fonts does not appear to work. Only relevant code is given below, main font settings and usage of bold text, MWE is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwwhEMUIYGyTSDM5Z21WR0VBWjA). ***How can I get bold fonts on Linux Libertine to work with this CV template?***

```
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures={TeX,Common},
  BoldFont={Linux Libertine O},
]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[
  Ligatures={TeX,Common},
  Letters=SmallCaps,
  Color=660000,
]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.85]{FontAwesome}

\begin{document}\flushbottom
\pagestyle{fancy} \setlength\headwidth{6.5in}
\rhead{\textsc{paul d.~gessler—r\'{e}sum\'{e}—\thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage}}} \cfoot{}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.85in}
\smallskip
\mhead{Education}%
\textbf{Marquette University,} Milwaukee, Wisconsin \newline
\emph{Master of Science, \href{http://www.marquette.edu/engineering/mechanical/}{Mechanical Engineering}} \rdate{2012–2014}
\begin{itemize*}
  \item Cumulative GPA: 3.44/4.00; {Energy Systems Specialization}
  \item Thesis: \href{https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10724484/resume/pdg_thesis.pdf}{One-Dimensional Model of a Refrigeration Cycle Compressor Test Block}
  \item Advisor: Dr.~Margaret M.~Mathison
\end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are telling `fontspec` to use _normal_ Linux Libertine O wherever a bold font is requested. Try to remove the `BoldFont` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setsansfont[
  Ligatures={TeX,Common},
  Letters=SmallCaps,
  Color=660000,
]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.85]{FontAwesome}%% THAT is NOT a monofont!

\usepackage{luatex85}% only needed for TL/MikTeX 2016

% \usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{microtype}

\def\myauthor{Paul Gessler}
[...]
```

and delete the complete `\setmainfont` stuff

[image]

Comment: Why does your code show “Biolinum” and the image “Libertine”?

Comment: because I uploaded the wrong image ...